# Parsing metadata text files with Python

Tags: python, imagery, metadata, geoeye

I am trying to use python to parse the .pvl metadata file from some GeoEye imagery. I would like to write a script that locates the productCloudCover and countryCode tags found within the .pvl. Does anyone know where I could find information on how to do this?

The structure of the file is as follows.

```
copyright = "######"
companyAddress = "########"
BEGIN_GROUP = "product order info"
     projectName = "#######"
     BEGIN_GROUP = "#####"   
         productCloudCover = "0.2"
     END_GROUP
END_GROUP = "product order inf"
```

Thanks

Comment: What is a PVL file? Doing a cursory internet search, it appears PVL is an extension used for cell phone backups and for some sort of installation information.

Comment: .pvl is also used in GeoEye imagery metadata. I am trying to get the cloude cover data for a series of images.

Answer (score 2):

I see the [release notes for GDAL 1.10](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/1.10.0-News) talk about having added the ability to read .pvl metadata. You might just skip python altogether and use [gdalinfo](/questions/tagged/gdalinfo).

---

This could be a straight python text parsing question, not specifically GIS. A simplistic implementation might look like this:

sample.pvl:

```
copyright = "(c) 2014 XYZ corp"
companyAddress = "123 Park Lane"
BEGIN_GROUP = "product order info"
    projectName = "Ramadian Parkland"
    BEGIN_GROUP = "this is a group"   
         productCloudCover = "0.2"
    END_GROUP
END_GROUP = "product order info"
```

parse-pvl.py:

```
fname = "sample.pvl"

pvl_dict = {}
for line in open(fname):
    line = line.strip() # strip leading and trailing whitespace
    if not "GROUP" in line: # skip lines containing "GROUP"
        key,value = str.split(line, ' = ')
        pvl_dict[key] = value

print "Project:\t", pvl_dict['projectName']
print "Clouds:\t\t", pvl_dict['productCloudCover']
```

Results in:

```
Project:    "Ramadian Parkland"
Clouds:     "0.2"
```

Not addressed are things like dealing with quotes, or extra `=` characters. For more help on dealing with those ask on Stack Overflow.